# htaccess rewrite get parameter in subdirectory and retrieve with php

Tags: php, .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting, get

I try rewriting `example.com/subdir/file.php?param=123` to `example.com/subdir/file/123` and retrieve the value in php.

In the `.htaccess` in the main directory i wrote
`RewriteRule ^/subdir/([^/.]+)/?$ /subdir/file.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this rule in site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteRule ^(subdir/[\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?param=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

- Pattern needs to match `file` part also after `subdir/`
- Use a capture group and back-reference to avoid repeating same text
- Leading `/` in regex pattern is not matched in `.htaccess`
- This assumes there is no other .htaccess in `subdir/`.